# Webview change height size

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I have a webview with content html, and I want the borders of the webview take all the screen as the picture below
[image]

Here my code:

```
webView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8")

webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
```

My xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.emoonadev.mickael.gestioclientel.Activities.PreviewPDFActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/app_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>A simple, clean, and responsive HTML invoice template</title>

    <style>
                .invoice-box {
                    max-width: 800px;
                    margin: auto;
                    padding: 30px;
                    border: 1px solid #eee;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
                    font-size: 16px;
                    line-height: 24px;
                    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    color: #555;
                }

            .invoice-box table {
                width: 100%;
                line-height: inherit;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .invoice-box table td {
                padding: 5px;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2) {
                text-align: right;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title {
                font-size: 45px;
                line-height: 45px;
                color: #333;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.heading td {
                background: #eee;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.details td {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.item td{
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.item.last td {
                border-bottom: none;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2) {
                border-top: 2px solid #eee;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }

            /** RTL **/
            .rtl {
                direction: rtl;
                font-family: Tahoma, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }

            .rtl table {
                text-align: right;
            }

            .rtl table tr td:nth-child(2) {
                text-align: left;
            }

            #space{

            }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="invoice-box">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="top">
            <td colspan="6">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="title">
                            <img src="#LOGO#" style="width:50%; max-width:300px;"/>
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <strong><h2> #INVOICE_NUMBER# </h2></strong><br/>
                            Created: #INVOICE_DATE#
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="information">
            <td colspan="6">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            #COMPANY_NAME#<br/>
                            #COMPANY_PHONE#<br/>
                            #COMPANY_ADDRESS#<br/>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            #USER_NAME#<br/>
                            #USER_PHONE#<br/>
                            #USER_ADDRESS#<br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="heading">
            <td>
                Item
            </td>

            <td>
                <center>Unit price HT</center>
            </td>

            <td>
                <center>Quantity</center>
            </td>

            <td>
                <center>HT</center>
            </td>

            <td>
                <center>VAT</center>
            </td>

            <td>
                <center>Price</center>
            </td>
        </tr>

        #ITEMS#

        <tr class="total">
            <td>
                <div id="space"><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
                Total HT: #TOTAL_HT#<br/>
                VAT #VAT# %: #TOTAL_VAT#<br/>
                Discount: #DISCOUNT#<br/>
                Total TTC: #TOTAL_TTC#<br/>
                #TOTAL_AFTER_DISCOUNT#
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you

Comment: post your xml code.

Comment: check update...

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen he means, paste your layout.xml code so that we can see the view attributes

Comment: it's html not xml ;)

Comment: Sorry >_< check update now please :)

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen your xml is alright the problem is in your html code. Also make sure to remove the HTML's margins/padding which you are rendering into the WebView that might contain those tags which leaves some space

Comment: can you show html code?

Comment: Check update please

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time identifying which aspect of your code is associated with the content box you want to be displayed across the whole screen.

You need to identify the code and use the CSS property height.
I think .invoice-box is the correct class identifier but I cannot be certain.

```
.invoice-box {
    height: 100%;
}
```

using percentages for the content box will always assure that the box takes up 100% of the window height.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me but not working

Comment: perhaps it is the incorrect class selector then that I am using?